# Does gcc or other compilers auto convert bitwise or's to boolean or's when used in conditional expressions?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

If I have a C statement with the logical OR operator `||` :

```
if (isFoo() || isBar())
    blah();
```

I know the compiler generated code will not execute `isBar()` if `isFoo()` returns true.

What about the bitwise OR operator | ?

```
if (isFoo() | isBar())
    blah();
```

Likely this is sloppy writing, or if the writer *requires* `isBar()` *and* `isFoo()` to be both be executed because of those functions' side-effects, then they should express their intent more clearly.  Or maybe I'm wrong and this is an acceptable C/C++ idiom.

Nevertheless, will a decent compiler actually generate a temporary variable to do the bitwise or'ing of the return values of `isFoo()` and `isBar()` when optimizations are turned on?  Or will it instead convert the bitwise OR operation into a logical OR operation in order to allow short-circuit'ing of the boolean expression in order to prevent the calling of `isBar()`?

Comment: It must call both functions (in no particular order).

Comment: Why dont you try compiling and running it ?  That helps sometime. :)

Comment: I was curious about the spec as well as more the behavior of compilers that I don't access to.  Additionally, I was curious about the acceptability of such code.  Perhaps I could have run with `gcc -O3` and then someday I'll find out that Microsoft's compiler has an additional optimization.  Thus, I wanted to know the correct answer, not a specific compiler implementation.

Comment: @Ajeet: Compile/test is rarely a valid way to answer questions like this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler is free to optimize the "or'ing" however it wants, but the program must behave as if **both** function calls actually happen, and they could happen in **either order**. This actually bit me once when I naively changed a `||` to `|` because I needed both calls to happen, but forgot that the right-hand call could happen before the left-hand one and that the right-hand one depended on the results of the left-hand one...and the bug didn't show up until somebody decided to try compiling my code with `pcc` instead of `gcc`. So my advice is to be careful with stuff like this and write out what you mean clearly.

Finally, note that I said "as if both function calls actually happen", because in the case where the compiler can determine that a function has no side effects, it might optimize out the right-hand side if the left-hand side resulted in a nonzero value.

Comment: Or equivalently it might optimize out the left-hand one if it determines that `left()` has no side effects and `right()` returns a non-zero.

Comment: Or it might optimize out a `||` (two branches) to a `|` if it determines that both functions have no side effects and become trivial when inlined. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> "Nevertheless, will a decent compiler actually generate a temporary
>   variable to do the bitwise or'ing of the return values of isFoo() and
>   isBar() when optimizations are turned on?"

Yes. Short circuiting does not apply to bitwise operators.

Comment: Is this reasonable coding practice and I'm the last one to hear about it?

Comment: @Ross:  I have never seen anyone do this intentionally.  I won't say it's unreasonable, but I think someone looking at it without a comment might think it's a typo and just change it to a logical operator.

Comment: Ok.  Warrants a comment.  I buy that.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll go ahead and say it *is* unreasonable, or at least very ill-advised. Using `||` on "isX" boolean functions is such a common pattern that it's not unlikely someone working on the code will change `|` to `||` without even realizing it. (Of course, "is" functions with side-effects are a code smell of their own...)

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a reasonable coding practice.  Apart from `||`'s short-circuit and ordering semantics, it performs a different operation than `|`.

`||` yields 1 if either operand is non-zero, 0 if both are zero.

`|` yields the *bitwise* or of its operands.

As it happens, the truth value of the result is going to be the same (I realized this as I was typing this answer).  But consider the corresponding `&&` vs. `&` operators.  This:

```
if (isFoo() && isBar())
```

will be true if and only if both functions return a non-zero value, but this:

```
if (isFoo() & isBar())
```

will be true if and only if the *bitwise* and of the results is non-zero.  If `isFoo()` returns 1 and `isBar()` returns 2 (both true results), then `isFoo & isBar()` will be 0, or false.

Note that the `is*()` functions declared in `<ctype.h>` are only specified to return non-zero for true; they can and do return values other than 0 or 1.

If you really want to avoid the short-circuit behavior of `||`, assign the results to temporaries:

```
bool is_foo = isFoo();
bool is_bar = isBar();
if (is_foo && is_bar) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

We are talking straight C here so we must have something like

```
typedef int BOOL;
BOOL isFoo();
BOOL isBAr();
```

This is because ony C++ (and not C) has a boolean type.

Now when we evaluate `isFoo() || isBar()` the compiler knows that since we are using **logical** or if isFoo() returns true, the the whole statement will evaluate to true regardless of the value of isBar(), the compiler can therefore safely short circuit `isBar().

However when we evaluate isFoo() | isBar() we are effectively ORing two integers. The compiler has no way of knowing that isFoo() and isBar() can only return 0 or 1 and therefore will have to evaluate both expressions because even if isFoo() returns 1, the final result may be something different (like 3).

C++ does have a `bool` type and if `isFoo()` and `isBar()` return `bool`s the compiler really does not have to evalueate `isBar()`. I am not an expert on the C++ specification but I imagine since bitwise operators do not make sense for `bool` types, the `bool`s will be promoted to `int` and evaluated accordingly.

Comment: The crux of the issue is that the compiler _could_ infer the semantic meaning of the `if` statement which means that the result of the bitwise OR operation is only important for non-zero testing, so the _actual_ result of the bitwise operation is inconsequential.  As the other answers have stated, the compiler could then short-circuit the OR operation if the 2nd expression had no side-effects in either C or C++.

Comment: C has a boolean type: `_Bool` and `<stdbool.h>` have been a part of the language for **12 years**.

Comment: @doron: If K&R had wanted to, they could have defined the bitwise Boolean operators to have short-circuit behavior.  If the left-hand operand of a bitwise 'or' returns an all-bits-set value, the result will be all-bits-set, regardless of the value of the right-hand operand.  The reason the bitwise operators don't short-circuit is that the spec says they don't.  Nothing more; nothing less.